# GDAL utility in Bash for loop (Ubuntu)

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, loop

In Windows GDAL terminal (in Windows, GDAL has a specific terminal/prompt) I usually do loops and it works like a charm.

What I'm trying to do the same in a Shell terminal in Ubuntu with the following syntax:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of KEA %i %~ni_new.kea
```

Considering I'm in the right folder, I don't need to specify any path. I know Ubuntu (trusty in my case) has a different syntax but even after several tries, I can't figure out how it works in Ubuntu terminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: This really isn't a question of GDAL functionality, but how to do a for loop in a shell. It's likely that your GDAL environment is using a ported version of BASH or SH or something compatible, but it will depend on what distribution you are using (OSGEO?). For Ubuntu, you just need to determine what shell you are using, most likely BASH, and [research how to do a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181307/for-loop-in-bash-script) there.

Comment: "in windows, gdal has a specific terminal/prompt)" - Do you happen to mean the Osgeo4w command prompt/environment? GDAL itself does not have a specific command prompt no matter the OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux (ubuntu as you call it) uses a shell (probably bash in this case) which has a different syntax to windows so you want something like:

```
for i in se70*.tif 
do
  gdalinfo $i
done
```

Comment: that's great! It worked. Just a little detail: in windows, the statement %~ni_new.kea parses the file name, so the outputs has the same file name with _new added. In linux terminal It seems not working like windows. Would you know how can I "translate" this to linux?

Comment: bash has a similar thing, `$i{%%.tif}_new.tif` , which will strip the `.tif` from the filename, then append `_new.tif`. Try it out with the "echo" command first to see how it works. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118236/clip-raster-by-shapefile-in-parts/118241#118241 for similar code.