How to use gdal calc.py for batch processing in MAC OS
I have .tif files for Novemeber starting from 2001 to 2020, with values ranging from 1-255. I only want values from 1 to 100 and anything above 100 as NoDataValue. I was able to execute the code for a single file gdal_calc.py -A inoutfile.tif --calc="(A<101)*A" --NoDataValue -9999 --outfile output.tif. Now I want to loop in all the files for batch process. I'm very new to batch processing in gdal and don't have much experience with loops in python. The code I used for batch processing is
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
   echo %%~nf
   gdal_calc.py -A %%f --calc="(A<101)*A" --NoDataValue -9999 --outfile %%~nf.tif
)

But when I'm running it on terminal it says
./nodata.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./nodata.sh: line 1: `for %%f in (*.tif) do ('

How to do I loop in all the files?

Its MAC OS Catalina

@user2856 I have mentioned my operating system in the title now.

This isn't a python loop, it's a bash shell loop and you're trying to use Windows batch syntax.  Try a search for "bash for loop files". You'll get resuls for Linux and MacOS, they both use the same shell. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/177704/2856 https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

MacOS uses bash scripting at the command line. For-loops have a special syntax, and variable substitution is done with $name syntax.
I think your code roughly translates to this:
mkdir outputs
for f in *.tif ; do
  echo $f
  echo gdal_calc.py -A $f --calc="(A<101)*A" --NoDataValue -9999 --outfile outputs/$f
done

although I'm not sure what %%~nf translates to, given f. In the above, I've echoed the input file name and directed to outputs to a separate folder.
Also note I've prepended "echo" to the gdal_calc line, this shows me what the script is going to do. If that looks good, re-run without "echo" on that line and it will execute the code.
One issue that crops up with bash programming is to beware of space characters in your filenames... But read a good book on bash scripting to figure that all out...
