# How to mask extract/clip many rasters by a .shp file in python gdal?

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, gdal

I want to batch extract raster(.tif) covered by a vector file(.shp).
how to operate in python？ Could you give an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clip raster by shapefile in parts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118236/clip-raster-by-shapefile-in-parts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Linux/Mac, you could try the following. It makes use of glob (filename matching) to search for '.tif' files in the current directory. [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) is used to subset the rasters.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

ImageList = sorted(glob.glob('*.tif'))

Shapefile = 'Name_of_Vector.shp'

TargetRes = '10 10' # Defines the target resolution

# Create output directory
OutDir = './Clipped_Rasters/'
if not os.path.exists(OutDir):
    os.makedirs(OutDir)

for Image in ImageList:
    print('Processing ' + Image)

    OutImage = OutDir + Image.replace('.tif', '_Clipped.tif') # Defines Output Image

    # Clip image
    subprocess.call('gdalwarp -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -tr '+TargetRes+ ' -cutline ' +Shapefile+ ' -crop_to_cutline ' +Image+ ' ' +OutImage, shell=True)

    # Build image overviews
    subprocess.call('gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE ' +OutImage+ ' 2 4 8 16 32 64', shell=True)

    print('Done.' + '\n')

print('All images processed.')
```

There are other useful options for gdalwarp. For example, nearest neighbour resampling is used by default, but you can change this using the '-r' option. You can also specify the nodata value using the '-dstnodata' command.

Comment: Are there any tutorial for operate gdalwarp? Such as type the code format, grammar. I really confused!

Comment: Need it to install win exe `GDAL-2.1.2.win32-py3.4.msi`?  The `gdal` I use is installed by `conda`.  How to call the `gdalwarp`

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't use Windows, so I can't help with your installation problems.

Comment: The above script will work on unix systems where gdalwarp can be called (within Bash shell) through the subprocess module. This should also work in a conda environment as long as you have set the correct environment paths to Python.