# Clipping raster using multiple shapefiles using gdal in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I am currently using batch process in QGIS based on `clip raster by extent` to clip geotiff raster layers based on different shapefiles. I am trying to clip many raster layers from the same region with multiple discrete shapefiles. I previously tried `gdalwarp` but this approach changed the image dimension. Can anyone suggest a way in Python to automate the raster clipping based on multiple shapefiles?

---

Example of a raster layer and few shapefiles:

[image]

---

I merged all the shapefiles to one file and tested the code from the link below in jupyter notebook, but it returns error.
[Clipping raster with multiple polygons and naming the resulting rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294115/clipping-raster-with-multiple-polygons-and-naming-the-resulting-rasters)

```
import glob, os
import fiona
from subprocess import Popen

path= 'C:/dataset'
os.chdir(path)

with fiona.open('polygons.shp', 'r') as dst_in:
    for index, feature in enumerate(dst_in):
        with fiona.open('separated/polygon{}.shp'.format(index), 'w', **dst_in.meta) as dst_out:
            dst_out.write(feature)

polygons = glob.glob('separated/*.shp')  ## Retrieve all the .shp files

for polygon in polygons:
    feat = fiona.open(polygon, 'r')
    name = feat['properties']['name']  #name of the attribute considering the region name
    command = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline {} ' \
              '-crop_to_cutline -of GTiff ./input.tiff ./outputraster/{}.tiff'.format(polygon, name)
    Popen(command, shell=True)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8ce8105d9f76> in <module>
      8 for polygon in polygons:
      9     feat = fiona.open(polygon, 'r')
---> 10     name = feat['properties']['name']  #name of the attribute considering the region name
     11     command = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline {} ' \
     12               '-crop_to_cutline -of GTiff ./input.tiff ./outputraster/{}.tiff'.format(polygon, name)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hi Sam.  Are you concerned with the processing time itself or are you manually running the tool for every raster / shapefile clipping combination?  Also please clarify - are you using multiple shapefiles to clip multiple rasters?  My guess is you have many rasters to apply the same clipping operation to with multiple shapefiles.  Just checking.

Comment: @ NW_Photo_Laureate, I have many raster layers from the same geographic region and also multiple shapefiles (polygons) from this study area. I want to repeat the clipping task for each raster layer using the discrete multiple polygons.

Comment: gdal `clip raster by extent` uses a bounding box by the way.  So N, S, E, W essentially.  If your shapefiles are not boxes aligned with the x, y coords then a different gdal tool / qgis function will be necessary.  Are your shapefiles bounding boxes?

Comment: @ NW_Photo_Laureate, all the shapefiles are square covering 128x128 pixels. The N, S, E , and W coordinates are floating numbers. After performing the clip with gdal, raster dimension becomes 127x127 with integer coordinates for N, S, E , and W. Apart from gdal, "clip raster by extent" in QGIS does the task but it needs lots of repetitions.

Comment: @ NW_Photo_Laureate, I tested a code as mentioned in the question, but it returns error.

Comment: You're using `-crop_to_cutline` which is meant to modify the image dimensions:  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-crop_to_cutline  Look better if you remove that?

Comment: @ mikewatt, I want to crop to the extent of the shapefiles. I shouldn't use "-crop_to_cutline"?, I added an image in the question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misinterpreted what you were trying to do